# How to make a simple gallery slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The company that's my working now is making the web template.
I'm a web designer. I would like to make a simple gallery slide.
I searched in Internet, like Youtube, post on stackoverflow and the gradually write myself.
But now i have a problem. I can not make it slide.

**My idea is:**
When click **#left-arrow**, move left one piece and click **#right-arrow**, move right one piece.

if **:last-child**, reture back to the first picture.

And in the future it will be responsive.(In this section, if too difficult do it later)

Please help me

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var page_body = $('#page-body').width();
  var width_li = 0;
  var margin_items_slide = 5;
  var items_show = 3;
  var calc_width_container = ((items_show * margin_items_slide) + page_body) - margin_items_slide;
  $(".container-slide").css('max-width', calc_width_container);
  $(".container-slide ul > li").css('width', page_body / items_show);
  $(".container-slide ul > li").css({marginRight: margin_items_slide + 'px'});
  $('.container-slide ul > li').each(function() {
    width_li += $(this).outerWidth(true);
  });
  $('.container-slide-overflow > ul').css('width', width_li + margin_items_slide);

  $('#right-arrow').on('click', function() {
  // even i can not make it
  });
  $('#left-arrow').on('click', function() {
// even i can not make it
  });



  $(window).resize(function() {
  var page_body = $('#page-body').width();
  var width_li = 0;
  var margin_items_slide = 5;
  var items_show = 3;
  var calc_width_container = ((items_show * margin_items_slide) + page_body) - margin_items_slide;
  $(".container-slide").css('max-width', calc_width_container);
  $(".container-slide ul > li").css('width', page_body / items_show);
  $(".container-slide ul > li").css({marginRight: margin_items_slide + 'px'});
  $('.container-slide ul > li').each(function() {
    width_li += $(this).outerWidth(true);
  });
  $('.container-slide-overflow > ul').css('width', width_li + margin_items_slide);

  $('#right-arrow').on('click', function() {
  // even i can not make it
  });
  $('#left-arrow').on('click', function() {
// even i can not make it
  });
  
 });
 
 
 
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#page-body {
  width: 350px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.container-slide ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

.container-slide ul:before,
.container-slide ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.container-slide ul:after {
  clear: both;
}

.container-slide ul>li {
  float: left;
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 50px;
}

.container-slide-overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container-slide {
  position: relative;
}

.container-slide button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}

#left-arrow {
  left: -15px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#right-arrow {
  right: -15px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

@media(max-width:350px) {
  #page-body {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #left-arrow {
    left: 0px;
  }
  #right-arrow {
    right: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page-body">
  <div class="container-slide">
    <div class="container-slide-overflow">
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="box-arrow-control">
      <button id="left-arrow">←</button>
      <button id="right-arrow">→</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Try this it will work fine according to your requirement
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var page_body = $('#page-body').width();
    var width_li = 0;
    var margin_items_slide = 5;
    var items_show = 3;
    var calc_width_container = ((items_show * margin_items_slide) + page_body) - margin_items_slide;
    $(".container-slide").css('max-width', calc_width_container);
    $(".container-slide ul > li").css('width', page_body / items_show);
    $(".container-slide ul > li").css({
     marginRight : margin_items_slide + 'px'
    });
    $('.container-slide ul > li').each(function() {
     width_li += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    });
    $('.container-slide-overflow > ul').css('width', width_li + margin_items_slide);

    $(".container-slide ul li").eq(0).addClass("active");
    var liWidth = $(".container-slide ul").width() / $(".container-slide ul li").length;

    $('#right-arrow').on('click', function() {
     if ($(".container-slide ul li").length - items_show > $(".container-slide ul li.active").index()) {

      setLiWidth = liWidth * ($(".container-slide ul li.active").index() + 1);
      
      $(".container-slide ul li.active").next("li").addClass("active");
      $(".container-slide ul li.active").eq(0).removeClass("active")
      $(".container-slide ul").animate({
       left : -setLiWidth
      }, 1000)
     } else {
      $(".container-slide ul li").eq(0).addClass("active").siblings("li").removeClass("active");
      $(".container-slide ul").animate({
       left : 0
      }, 1000)
     }

    });

    $('#left-arrow').on('click', function() {

     if (0 < $(".container-slide ul li.active").index()) {

      setLiWidth = liWidth * ($(".container-slide ul li.active").index() - 1);
      
      $(".container-slide ul li.active").prev("li").addClass("active");
      $(".container-slide ul li.active").eq(1).removeClass("active")
      $(".container-slide ul").animate({
       left : -setLiWidth
      }, 1000)
     } else {
      $(".container-slide ul li").eq($(".container-slide ul li").length - items_show).addClass("active").siblings("li").removeClass("active");
      setLiWidth = liWidth * ($(".container-slide ul li.active").index());
      $(".container-slide ul").animate({
       left : -setLiWidth
      }, 1000)
     }
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
     var page_body = $('#page-body').width();
     var width_li = 0;
     var margin_items_slide = 5;
     var items_show = 3;
     var calc_width_container = ((items_show * margin_items_slide) + page_body) - margin_items_slide;
     $(".container-slide").css('max-width', calc_width_container);
     $(".container-slide ul > li").css('width', page_body / items_show);
     $(".container-slide ul > li").css({
      marginRight : margin_items_slide + 'px'
     });
     $('.container-slide ul > li').each(function() {
      width_li += $(this).outerWidth(true);
     });
     $('.container-slide-overflow > ul').css('width', width_li + margin_items_slide);

     $('#right-arrow').on('click', function() {
      // even i can not make it
     });
     $('#left-arrow').on('click', function() {
      // even i can not make it
     });

    });

   });
```

```css
  * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
   }

   #page-body {
    width: 350px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
   }

   .container-slide ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
   }

   .container-slide ul:before, .container-slide ul:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
   }

   .container-slide ul:after {
    clear: both;
   }

   .container-slide ul > li {
    float: left;
    background: orange;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 50px;
   }

   .container-slide-overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
   }

   .container-slide {
    position: relative;
   }

   .container-slide button {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
    border: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
   }

   #left-arrow {
    left: -15px;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
   }

   #right-arrow {
    right: -15px;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
   }

   @media (max-width: 350px) {
    #page-body {
     width: 100%;
    }
    #left-arrow {
     left: 0px;
    }
    #right-arrow {
     right: 0px;
    }
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page-body">
   <div class="container-slide">
    <div class="container-slide-overflow">
     <ul>
      <li>
       1
      </li>
      <li>
       2
      </li>
      <li>
       3
      </li>
      <li>
       4
      </li>
      <li>
       5
      </li>
      <li>
       6
      </li>
      <li>
       7
      </li>
      <li>
       8
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="box-arrow-control">
     <button id="left-arrow">
      ←
     </button>
     <button id="right-arrow">
      →
     </button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Its beauty of run snippet. You can get result right here. This slider makes me remember the flexslider plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing simple concept about slide. You can play with index of active items of slider. Here I have added `active` class to the items which are display currently and when `right-arrow` is clicked I make first active item hidden and displayed item next to last active item. Similarly when `left-arrow` is clicked I make last active item hidden and item previous to first active item has been displayed. Hope it helped to understand the concept.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var page_body = $('#page-body').width();
  var width_li = 0;
  var margin_items_slide = 5;
  var items_show = 3;
  var calc_width_container = ((items_show * margin_items_slide) + page_body) - margin_items_slide;
  $(".container-slide").css('max-width', calc_width_container);
  $(".container-slide ul > li").css('width', page_body / items_show);
  $(".container-slide ul > li").css({marginRight: margin_items_slide + 'px'});
  $('.container-slide ul > li').each(function() {
    width_li += $(this).outerWidth(true);
  });
  $('.container-slide-overflow > ul').css('width', width_li + margin_items_slide);

  $('#right-arrow').on('click', function() {
  // even i can not make it  
    if ($('li.active').last().next().length > 0){
      $('li.active').first().hide();
      $('li.active').first().removeClass('active');
      $('li.active').last().next().show();
      $('li.active').last().next().addClass('active');
    }
  });
  $('#left-arrow').on('click', function() {
  // even i can not make it
  if ($('li.active').first().prev().length > 0){
    $('li.active').first().prev().show();
    $('li.active').first().prev().addClass('active');
    $('li.active').last().hide();
    $('li.active').last().removeClass('active');
  }
  });



  $(window).resize(function() {
  var page_body = $('#page-body').width();
  var width_li = 0;
  var margin_items_slide = 5;
  var items_show = 3;
  var calc_width_container = ((items_show * margin_items_slide) + page_body) - margin_items_slide;
  $(".container-slide").css('max-width', calc_width_container);
  $(".container-slide ul > li").css('width', page_body / items_show);
  $(".container-slide ul > li").css({marginRight: margin_items_slide + 'px'});
  $('.container-slide ul > li').each(function() {
    width_li += $(this).outerWidth(true);
  });
  $('.container-slide-overflow > ul').css('width', width_li + margin_items_slide);

  $('#right-arrow').on('click', function() {
  // even i can not make it
  });
  $('#left-arrow').on('click', function() {
// even i can not make it
  });
  
 });
 
 
 
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#page-body {
  width: 350px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.container-slide ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

.container-slide ul:before,
.container-slide ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.container-slide ul:after {
  clear: both;
}

.container-slide ul>li {
  float: left;
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 50px;
}

.container-slide-overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container-slide {
  position: relative;
}

.container-slide button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}

#left-arrow {
  left: -15px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#right-arrow {
  right: -15px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

@media(max-width:350px) {
  #page-body {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #left-arrow {
    left: 0px;
  }
  #right-arrow {
    right: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page-body">
  <div class="container-slide">
    <div class="container-slide-overflow">
      <ul>
        <li class="active">1</li>
        <li class="active">2</li>
        <li class="active">3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="box-arrow-control">
      <button id="left-arrow">←</button>
      <button id="right-arrow">→</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Slide based on width of slide item.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var page_body = $('#page-body').width();
  var width_li = 0;
  var margin_items_slide = 5;
  var items_show = 3;
  var calc_width_container = ((items_show * margin_items_slide) + page_body) - margin_items_slide;
  $(".container-slide").css('max-width', calc_width_container);
  $(".container-slide ul > li").css('width', page_body / items_show);
  $(".container-slide ul > li").css({marginRight: margin_items_slide + 'px'});
  $('.container-slide ul > li').each(function() {
    width_li += $(this).outerWidth(true);
  });
  $('.container-slide-overflow > ul').css('width', width_li + margin_items_slide);

  $('#right-arrow').on('click', function() {
  // even i can not make it  
    if ($('li.active').last().next().length > 0){
      $('li.active').first().removeClass('active');
      $('li.active').last().next().addClass('active');
      var prevmargin = $("ul").css("margin-left").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
      var newmargin = prevmargin - ($('li').outerWidth() + 5);
      $('ul').css({"margin-left": newmargin});
      
    }
  });
  $('#left-arrow').on('click', function() {
  // even i can not make it
  if ($('li.active').first().prev().length > 0){
    $('li.active').first().prev().addClass('active');
    $('li.active').last().removeClass('active');
    var prevmargin = $("ul").css("margin-left").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
    var newmargin = prevmargin + ($('li').outerWidth() + 5);
    $('ul').css({"margin-left": newmargin});
  }
  });



  $(window).resize(function() {
  var page_body = $('#page-body').width();
  var width_li = 0;
  var margin_items_slide = 5;
  var items_show = 3;
  var calc_width_container = ((items_show * margin_items_slide) + page_body) - margin_items_slide;
  $(".container-slide").css('max-width', calc_width_container);
  $(".container-slide ul > li").css('width', page_body / items_show);
  $(".container-slide ul > li").css({marginRight: margin_items_slide + 'px'});
  $('.container-slide ul > li').each(function() {
    width_li += $(this).outerWidth(true);
  });
  $('.container-slide-overflow > ul').css('width', width_li + margin_items_slide);

  $('#right-arrow').on('click', function() {
  // even i can not make it
  });
  $('#left-arrow').on('click', function() {
// even i can not make it
  });
  
 });
 
 
 
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#page-body {
  width: 350px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.container-slide ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

.container-slide ul:before,
.container-slide ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.container-slide ul:after {
  clear: both;
}

.container-slide ul>li {
  float: left;
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 50px;
}

.container-slide-overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container-slide {
  position: relative;
}

.container-slide button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}

#left-arrow {
  left: -15px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#right-arrow {
  right: -15px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

@media(max-width:350px) {
  #page-body {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #left-arrow {
    left: 0px;
  }
  #right-arrow {
    right: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page-body">
  <div class="container-slide">
    <div class="container-slide-overflow">
      <ul>
        <li class="active">1</li>
        <li class="active">2</li>
        <li class="active">3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="box-arrow-control">
      <button id="left-arrow">←</button>
      <button id="right-arrow">→</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much, but animate not smooth. 
i think, it should use translateX(width of li + 'px');

Comment: What should I do When clicked, the value of the variable in translateY is incremented.

For example, if li width is 116.667, click the first time is -116.667 and click the second time is - 233.334 and the next time you add more

Comment: @siwakorn you can use jquery animation